# mysql error: #1052 - Column 'id' in from clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I need join twice for same table - age so I can order by one field of age, how come is it?

> mysql error: #1052 - Column 'id' in from clause is ambiguous

```
select * from `students` `s` JOIN `age` `a` on `s`.`SN`=`a`.`SN` JOIN (SELECT `s`.`id` FROM `students` `s` JOIN `age` `a` on `s`.`SN`=`a`.`SN` WHERE 1 order by `a`.`age` asc limit 0,2) p using(id) order by `a`.`age` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is actually *ambiguous*, explicitly specify the table name, replace:

```
using(id)
```

with:

```
using(p.id)
```